# Imgui create pop up box removing the grayed out focus screen

Tags: c++, windows, glfw, imgui

when creating a pop up modal in ImGui, I noticed that there is a grey overlay that appears over the rest of the application (to put the focus on the pop up I think).

However, I am wondering if there is a way for me to remove that gray overlay screen so that I can still interact with the rest of the application even when that modal is popped up. So the modal pops up but its not interferring with the rest of the application - just an information pop up to reflect the current speed until the user clicks OK to make the pop up go away.

This is the code I have for the modal window creation:

```
if (ImGui::BeginPopupModal("Speed Adjustment")) {
        std::string speed_text = "You're adjusting the speed";
        speed_text += "\n";
        ImGui::Text(speed_text.c_str());
        //list the current speed
        std::string currSpeed= "This is the current speed: " + std::to_string(databse->camSpeed);
        ImGui::Text(currSpeed.c_str());


        ImGui::Spacing();
        ImGui::NextColumn();

        ImGui::Columns(1);
        ImGui::Separator();

        ImGui::NewLine();

        ImGui::SameLine(GetWindowWidth() - 270);
        //click ok when finished adjusting
        if (ImGui::Button("OK finished adjusting", ImVec2(200, 0))) {
            speedpopup= false;
            ImGui::CloseCurrentPopup();
        }

        ImGui::EndPopup();
    }
```

Do I need to add certain flags for the beginPopupModal portion? If so, what flags should I use?

Thank you, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Modal generally implies that you cannot interact with anything else. Perhaps you just want a regular popup?

Comment: @RetiredNinja so what function should I use for a regular pop up? I don't want it to look like a window/tabbed window by using ImGui::Begin. So not sure what function I should use instead :) could u tell me? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the documentation in `imgui.h:659`

**Popups, Modals :**

- They block normal mouse hovering detection (and therefore most mouse interactions) behind them.
- If not modal: they can be closed by clicking anywhere outside them, or by pressing ESCAPE.
- Their visibility state (~bool) is held internally instead of being held by the programmer as we are used to with regular Begin*() calls.

If you want to interact with the rest of the application even when popped up is shown better go with a regular`ImGui::Begin()` call. Even you can use with appropriate flags to center the window as needed.

```
static bool speedpopup = true;
if (speedpopup) {
    if (ImGui::Begin("mypicker"))
    {
        std::string speed_text = "You're adjusting the speed";
        speed_text += "\n";
        ImGui::Text(speed_text.c_str());
        //list the current speed
        std::string currSpeed = "This is the current speed: ";
        ImGui::Text(currSpeed.c_str());

        ImGui::Spacing();
        ImGui::NextColumn();

        ImGui::Columns(1);
        ImGui::Separator();

        ImGui::NewLine();

        ImGui::SameLine(270);
        //click ok when finished adjusting
        if (ImGui::Button("OK finished adjusting", ImVec2(200, 0))) {
            speedpopup = false;
        }

        ImGui::End();
    }
}
```

Helper function like this can define a custom `Begin()`

```
bool BeginCentered(const char* name)
{
    ImGuiIO& io = ImGui::GetIO();
    ImVec2 pos(io.DisplaySize.x * 0.5f, io.DisplaySize.y * 0.5f);
    ImGui::SetNextWindowPos(pos, ImGuiCond_Always, ImVec2(0.5f, 0.5f));
    ImGuiWindowFlags flags = ImGuiWindowFlags_NoMove
        | ImGuiWindowFlags_NoDecoration
        | ImGuiWindowFlags_AlwaysAutoResize
        | ImGuiWindowFlags_NoSavedSettings;
    return ImGui::Begin(name, nullptr, flags);
}
```

The imgui documentation are clear in the headers.